# VS ReportViewer RDLC - how to prevent a table from pushing down other items?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a narrow table on a report with 6 columns. The table has to hold 1 - 4 rows, depending on the data. I designed the report so that there is enough white space to accommodate 4 rows. I want to use the space on the right side of the table. When I place text fields there, they get pushed down by the table as it expands to show additional rows. Is there a way to lock these text fields into place?

[image]
<sub>(source: [heeroz.com](http://heeroz.com/rpt.png))</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally figured this out. A rectangle works as a container for data regions. If I place the table into a rectangle, it will only grow within the boundaries of the rectangle, without pushing other report items around.
In order for this to work, though, the table must be a child control of the rectangle.  This is achieved by dropping a new table into an existing text box, or by dropping an existing table some place outside of the rectangle, then moving it back inside. If you just draw a rectangle around the table, it will not become a child. This can be verified by right-clicking on the table. If it only says "select body" and not "select rectanglexx" as well, it is not a child of the rectangle.
Alternatively, it is possible to place other items (text boxes, etc into a rectangle that is on one side of a table. The top edge of the rectangle must be above the bottom edge of the table. Then any controls in the rectangle will be unaffected by the growth of the table, but other items below the table will.

Comment: @SPQR i like a lot your nick! salve SPQR

Comment: Demential the lot of incredible bugs and things like this in RDLC at 2019.